# How to set flags for library objects using libtool

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, automake, libtool

I want to use libtool in order to build my library. My **Makefile.am** looks like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = mylib.la

mylib_la_SOURCES = source1.c source2.c
mylib_la_LIBADD = -lXLibray
```

The problem is that `source1` depends on `XLibrary` and when it tries to compile it in order to obtain the library object (`source1.lo`) it don't use the `-XLibrary` flag and it returns with error.

Do you have any idea about how can I solve this?

Comment: You might need to add a search path as well, for `foo.so` or `foo.dylib` (OS X) : `-L/path/to/foo -lfoo`

Comment: I did that too, but it still doesn't work